# django using formset to update multiple instances

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to update multiple instances at once, after searching I found `formset` but only came to know how to create multiple instances.

I need to update existing instances with one form.

for example I have model as

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    passed = models.BoolenField(default=False)
    hostel = models.Foreginkey( ... )
```

I need to update hostel for all passed students with one form.

How to do this ?

Comment: Can you post the `formset` code?